# node-sass install script ignore .npmrc settings

Tags: npm, node-sass

Try to install node-sass behind corporate proxy. I have configured nexus and set it in .npmrc

```
registry = http://dev/nexus/repository/npmjs_org/
strict-ssl = false
sass_binary_site = http://dev/nexus/repository/nodesass_downloads/
```

then I try to install packages

```
$ npm ci

> fsevents@1.2.7 install C:\***\ui\node_modules\fsevents
> node install


> fsevents@1.2.4 install C:\***\ui\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\fsevents
> node install


> node-sass@4.11.0 install C:\***\ui\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-57_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-57_binding.node":

getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall C:\***\ui\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

.......
```

As you can see `sass_binary_site` totally ignored. What is wrong?

Comment: my config uses sass-binary-site, not sass_binary_site ...

Comment: I'll check it at monday :)

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Partially, it works from command line `npm install --sass-binary-site=http://dev/nexus/repository/nodesass_downloads/`